# How to get different values for a Parameter in Run time?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, parameter-passing, testng

I need to Read email using Subject and value to Subject is passed in Run time in 3 different scenarios.

1. Performing an Operation which triggers an Email with Subject for the @Test is given in CSV file - class1.java
2. Performing an Operation which triggers an Email with Subject is given in @Parameters functionality - class2.java
3. Subject value is directly read from properties file - selenium.properties.

I m able to Read subject content from class1 and properties file. Now, I want to read @Parameter value which is passed from an XML file.

Below is my current code.

```
//Reads Subject from properties file.
if(subject==null||subject.isEmpty()) {    
     //Reads Subject from given CSV file.
     reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName), CoreConstants.CSV_FILE_SEPARATOR, CoreConstants.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER, CoreConstants.CSV_SKIP_HEADER_LINE);
     if((record = reader.readNext()) != null) {
         subject = record[18];                   
     }
}
```

Class1 & 2 contains @Test methods, when executing, they trigger mails. But, the above method is in helper class which does not contain @Test annotation.

Kindly help me to read value of Subject in scenario 2.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the answer is given in the [testng docs](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters):

If you are using simple values for your parameters, you can specify them in your testng.xml:

```
@Parameters({ "first-name" })
@Test
public void testSingleString(String firstName) {
  System.out.println("Invoked testString " + firstName);
  assert "Cedric".equals(firstName);
}
```

In this code, we specify that the parameter firstName of your Java method should receive the value of the XML parameter called first-name.  This XML parameter is defined in testng.xml:

```
<suite name="My suite">
  <parameter name="first-name"  value="Cedric"/>
  <test name="Simple example">
  <-- ... -->
```

Comment: Thanks!!... But method for reading email is not annotated with @Test. I edited my question to convey clearly.

Comment: @Bala the `@Test` method can pass expected parameters to you utils method.